# Forms not loading DB fields

Tags: ee2, forms, devdemon-forms

I have installed the forms module in a MSM site and even after logging in through the url listed in my general config, I'm getting the 
“Failed to load Default Forms Fields.. Refreshing the page might help.”
“Failed to load DB Fields.. Refreshing the page might help. DO NOT SAVE THE FORM!”
one two combo. I'm running ee v2.9.0 and forms 3.4.12. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: are you sure that url is totally the same include www?

Comment: I am. This is actually for a MSM site accessed through a subdomain, so I can't use www.

Comment: I'd contact DevDemon support about this.

Comment: Tyrel, Did you ever get this resolved?

Comment: No I did not. We had to find a different solution.

Comment: So what was that different solution?

Comment: So what was that different solution?

Comment: Sorry to say I have no idea what the solution ended up being. I was doing some free lance work for a company that had a site built with EE and they had me put my focus somewhere else.